# Drag and drop list item one page list view to another page list view in android

Tags: android

In my project action bar with tab. each tab loaded different fragment.each fragment show the different list view . How to drag and drop the list item to different fragment list. I need to remove the item from dragged list and that item add to dropped list.

For example in the below link is in grid view, but i want to the same functionality in list view.

https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid